# How access to selected items of a ListView from another class? in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have two views of WPF (Vista1.xaml and Vista2.xaml), and they are part of a MainWindow.xaml.
In the Vista1.xaml i have a listview, where the user selects some items by clicking and the Vista2.xaml has a button.
I want that when the user clicks on the button of Vista2.xaml, get the items that the user previously selected in the listview of Vista1.xaml.

I have class in the Vista1.xaml.cs ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown method that captures the user selects the item in the listview.
the code is as follows

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
            var item = sender as ListViewItem;
            if (item != null && item.IsSelected)
            {
               ...
            }
}
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Add a public property to you `MainPage` that contains the data you want to pass between `Vista1` and `Vista2`.  Then, in your event handler of Vista1, set the property and on the button click of Vista2 read the property.

Comment: you mean to MainWindows.xaml.cs ?

Comment: add the public property to the  MainWindows.xaml.cs class, and the program does not run